# Excel VBA macro to send multiple attachments based on cell values

Tags: vba, excel, email

I'm a beginner in VBA and am working on a macro to automate reports.  Basically, the macro goes through a spreadsheet where each row represents a different client.  The third column has the client name, the fourth column has the amount spent, fifth column is the recipient's e-mail address, and the sixth and seventh columns contain parts of the file path for a complete report.

It works fine if you want to generate an e-mail for each row, but now I want it to generate an e-mail including information from multiple rows.  My thought was that I would assign each e-mail a unique ID in column 2 and that it would skip generating the e-mail if the row had the same unique ID as the row before it, but it would include the numbers from column 4 and the attachments based on the file path in columns six and seven for all subsequent rows that were equal to that unique ID.  If column 2 went 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, for example, there would be 3 e-mails instead of 6.  The list is always going to be ordered correctly, so that's not a concern.

I'm not quite sure how to create the nested loop that would loop through all of the subsequent rows with equal values to the first cell in column 2 and then ignore them for the first loop.  I'd appreciate any suggestions.

```
Sub Test1()
Dim rng as Range
Dim OutApp as Object
Dim OutMail as Object
Dim r as Long

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For r = 2 to 8

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail 
     .To = rng.Cells(r,5).value
     .Subject = rng.Cells(r,3).value & " Report"
      If rng.Cells(r,2).value <> rng.cells.value(r+1,2) Then
            .HTMLBody = "This is how much was spent on the " & rng.Cells(r,3).Value & " account:" & rng.Cells(r,4),value
            .Attachments.Add (rng.Cells(r,6).value & rng.Cells(r,7).value)
      ElseIf rng.Cells(r,2).value = rng.Cells(r+1, 2) Then
            .HTMLBody = "This is how much was spent on the " & rng.Cells(r,3).Value & " account:" & rng.Cells(r,4).value & "</br>" & _
            "This is how much was spent on the " & rng.Cells(r+1,3).Value & " account:" & rng.Cells(r+1,4).value
            .Attachments.Add (rng.Cells(r,6).value & rng.Cells(r,7).value)
            .Attachments.Add (rng.Cells(r+1,6).value & rng.Cells(r+1,7).value)
      Else '
      End If
     .Display

 End With
 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing

 Next r
 End Sub
```

Comment: Definitely!  I've corrected that now.  Sorry about that and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the information in column 2 is in order, the following code should work:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim r As Long

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    r = 2

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Do While r <= rng.Rows.Count
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = rng.Cells(r, 5).Value
            .Subject = rng.Cells(r, 3).Value & " Report"
            .HTMLBody = "This is how much was spent on the " & rng.Cells(r, 3).Value & " account:" & rng.Cells(r, 4).Value
            .Attachments.Add (rng.Cells(r, 6).Value & rng.Cells(r, 7).Value)
            'See if the next row is for the same client.  If so, process that 
            'row as well.  And then keep doing it until no more rows match
            Do While rng.Cells(r, 2).Value = rng.Cells(r + 1, 2)
                r = r + 1
                .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</br>" & "This is how much was spent on the " & rng.Cells(r, 3).Value & " account:" & rng.Cells(r, 4).Value
                .Attachments.Add (rng.Cells(r, 6).Value & rng.Cells(r, 7).Value)
            Loop
            .Display

        End With
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you so much!